# Search specific tweets with Twitter API v2 - Bad Request

Tags: json, curl, twitter, bad-request, twitterapi-python

I am trying to get some information from specific tweets that have the keyword "covid" via Twitter's Full Archive.

```
import requests
import os
import json

def auth():
    return os.environ.get("BEARER_TOKEN")

def create_url():
    tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=created_at,retweet_count,lang"
    q = "covid" + "&start_time=2020-01-01T00:00:00.00Z&max_results=30" 
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?{}&{}".format(q, tweet_fields)
    return URL

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers


def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
           "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
               response.status_code, response.text
           )
        )
     return response.json()


def main():
    f = open(os.getcwd() + 'Tweets.txt', 'w')
    bearer_token = auth()
    url = create_url()
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)
    for i in json_response['data']:
        f.write('Text: ' + i['text'] )
        f.write('Retweets: ' + i['retweet_count'])
        f.write('Language: ' + i['lang'])

    f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but I am receiving the Error code 400 - Bad Request when I am calling i['retweet_count']

Comment: Simplify. I don't think you have authenticated properly. Check that first.